# How to save a Matplotlib 3D animation including changes in viewing angle during the animation

Tags: matplotlib, animation, 3d, save

I am a new Python programmer with a correctly running 3D scatter plot simulation.  Changing viewing angle during the simulation is important, as well as saving those changes.  I am able to save the simulation (relevant code below) but I cannot save and watch at the same time - just "save first, then watch".
My question: How can I watch the simulation, change the viewing angle, and save what I have watched, including those changes?
What I have tried:  No luck finding a similar question online. No help from studying Python help on FuncAnimation, animation.save, plt.plot(), or any other possibly relevant subject.

```
    """
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
    from matplotlib import animation as animation
    import math as math
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    matplotlib.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'C:\Users\harry\.ipython\ffmpeg-2021-07-25-git-a2a7547b2f-essentials_build\ffmpeg-2021-07-25-git-a2a7547b2f-essentials_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe'

    # Setup, calculate, define the plot. At the very end:

    save = False
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=nt, repeat=False, interval=1 )

    if save:
        f = r"D:\harry\Documents\Python_Scripts\3D\videos\scatter-TEST.mov"     
        writervideo = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30)
        anim.save(f, writer=writervideo)

    plt.show()
    """
```

Comment: I don't think that `matplotlib` can handle recording this sort of user input. Your best bet is probably a screen recording!

Comment: Thanks Ari.  I've found a Win 10 app called Game Bar which does just what you suggest.  It's a bit cumbersome, but it works!